# boost mpl wrap each element in a set

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to wrap each element in an `mpl::set` with some container, for example a `std::vector`, although the actual type is is not important. How would I do this? Basically I want to go from this

```
using mySet = mpl::set<int, float, double>;
```

to this

```
using myNewSet = mpl::set<container<int>, container<float>, container<double>>;
```

I thought of making a class similar to `mpl::insert`, however since I want the solution to be generic it has to somehow store the `container` type within itself, which doesn't play well with the parameter type of `mpl::fold`.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching, this seems to work fine:

```
using myNewSet = mpl::fold<
    mySet,
    mpl::set0<>,
    mpl::insert<mpl::_1, container<mpl::_2>
>::type;
```

Comment: you should also be able to use [transform](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/transform.html).

`mpl::transform<mySet, container<mpl::_1>>`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work since standard containers don't provide a typedef for `type`.

Comment: It should work nonetheless, notice that `mpl::transform` calls `mpl::lambda` internally, which then calls `mpl::quote`, which in turn implicitly defines a nested `::type` referring to the type itself, should no nested `::type` be defined.
However, it seems one can't transform `mpl::set`s due to a non related issue: it appears transform calls `mpl::push_front` internally, which is not defined for `mpl::set`. Indeed [it works for `mpl::vector`.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IeRGwrELRRItQLLU)